# Unity 2D C# Instantiate sprite on canvas. Can't find what's wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, instantiation

I read many questions about this, but I still can't find what my problem is...
I'm trying to instantiate a prefab at the canvas. It is compose of a button and a sprite. The button looks ok, but the sprite is not visible at the Game (but is visible at the Scene).

I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what...

```
 [SerializeField] GameObject finishedLevel;

     private void Start()
 {
     finishedLevel = Instantiate(finishedLevel, transform.position, transform.rotation);
     finishedLevel.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform, false);

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SpriteRenderer is not made to be used with the Canvas. You are confusing and misusing the two.

`SpriteRenderer` is used for displaying 2D Objects like a 2D animated character or a 2D environment. You can attach `Rigidbody2D` and `Colliders` to `SpriteRenderer`.

Canvas is used for UI display only. It is used for displaying things such as UI texts, buttons, sliders, scrollbars and images. You **shouldn't** attach Rigidbody2D and Colliders to it or its child objects.

With the explanation above, you should be able to determine which one to use. If you just need to display image under a Canvas, use the [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html), or [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) component since they are part of the UI system. This should work but *do not* make `SpriteRenderer` a child of a Canvas. If you have to use `SpriteRenderer`, make it its own object or under another object but it *should not* be under a Canvas. You may find Unity's UI [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui) useful.

Comment: At what point are unity going to realise they should hire you to write their manuals?