# Canvas With Box Colliders Confusion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, collision-detection

I have a canvas with Render Mode: Screen Space - Camera

Inside that I have square objects that I want collisions to be detected based off world view game objects. (Reason for this they need to scale based off device screen size)

I added a 2D box colliders to theses boxes but then get this error.

**Error:** this collider will not function with an effector until there is at least one enabled 2D effector on this GameObject

How can I detect Collisions of game objects in world view with tag "a" when they collide with my Canvas objects with tag "b"

Comment: Screen-space canvas objects should not ever collide with world space objects. The whole notion is flawed and you should re-evaluate your design to not need this.

Comment: Well then how do I get my Canvas Objects to change to game view and then scale to screen size so they don't go off the screen and they don't over lap? @Draco18s

Comment: Do not attach collider to a Canvas or its UI controls. If collision is needed on a 2D image, that's what SpriteRenderer is used for and that you can attach Collider 2D to. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51712450/3785314) for information.