# Unity3D Sprite not appear on Game Windows

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Hello

I try to add sprite to my unity 3D Project, on scene mode my sprite appear but when I start the game on game windows the sprite is not here, do you have an idea why the sprite is missing ?

[image]

Thanks a lot
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpriteRenderer is not a UI component so you shouldn't have it under the Canvas in the Hierarchy.

**1**.Move the Sprite Object from the Hierachy tab so that it's not a child of the Canvas.

**2**.Once you do this, you now have to reset the position of the Sprite to see it in the Game view. Start with making the position to be `0`,`0`,`0` then modify it from there. Also, the scale is too much. You may want to start with the default scale of `1`,`1`,`1` then move up from there.

It's always a good idea to make the `x`,`y`,`z` axis of the scale to be the-same. Currently they are not. If you want to change one dimension of a Sprite, it's better to modify the Sprite size with a 2D software like Photoshop. You will likely run into physics issue when you do this inside Unity.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51712450/3785314) post for difference between `SpriteRenderer` and UI objects such as the `Image` and `RawImage` components and when to use each one.